I have installed SQL Server 2019 via PowerShell but I am not able to open SSMS
I have installed SQL Server 2019 via PowerShell, the installation completed successfully, but I am not able to open SSMS (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio). I have one Windows server with working SSMS. I have logged in that server and type SSMS in all program and right click SSMS and "Open file location".
I have noticed Microsoft SQL Server Tools folder and SSMS binary was present in the folder. I have tried the same in the not working server. I was not able to find the folder at all. I have attached the both working and non working screenshots in the attachment. Also attached the screenshot of  package which I have installed. I have no idea what went wrong. Maybe configuration.ini file went wrong or something else.
Experts need your suggestion to fix this issue.
I am looking forward to hearing from you.
Thanks in advance




@marc_s  Hi Marc, Thanks much. Yes you are right. After I have downloaded and installed separately it started working. Could you please let me know how to make your answer as right answer.

@marc_s Thanks Marc. Marked your answer as correct answer

SQL Server - the core database components (engine) do not include SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).
You need to download SSMS separately and then install it afterwards.
